# NuGet packages local paths dont update after project folders reorder

Tags: .net, svn, nuget

There is a .NET solution committed to an SVN repository. After a developer reordered project folders tree (and re-parented some of items), the solution keeps working at his PC after commit but not at others because the relative paths to the local nuget packages storage in *.cproj files remains old.
What I've already tried:

- Enable package restore on build, clear local /packages folder,
  rebuild.
- Clear NuGet package cache and rebuild
- Open NuGet package
  manager, go through projects and uncheck-save-check-save one by one

The problem remains after any of above. The only troubleshoot that works is fixing paths in *.cproj files manually, and you can guess why I'm not happy about this.
Anyone knows a faster way? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix the hint paths by running the following in the Package Manager Console which reinstalls each package in each project:

```
update-package -reinstall
```

The NuGet packages will need to have been restored to the old locations before running this command.

I would make sure everything is under version control before running the above command.